# Java DBUnit AmbiguousTableNameException incorrectly thrown

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, dbunit, spring-test-dbunit

I'm experimenting with DBUnit (2.6.0) and I'm trying to export my full database (PostgreSQL). However the following exception is thrown:

> Exception in thread "main" org.dbunit.database.AmbiguousTableNameException: FLYWAY_SCHEMA_HISTORY

This is correct behaviour since I have two tables in different schemas with the same name:

[image]

I then read that you can set a property **Qualified Table Names** (http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/properties.html#qualifiedtablenames) that will take into account the schema name. So my code now is the following:

```
public class DbUnitExportTool {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // database connection
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

    Connection jdbcConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/*******", "********", "********");
    IDatabaseConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection(jdbcConnection);
    connection.getConfig().setProperty(DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_QUALIFIED_TABLE_NAMES, true);

    exportDatabase(connection);
}

private static void exportDatabase(IDatabaseConnection connection) throws Exception {
    // full database export
    IDataSet fullDataSet = connection.createDataSet();
    FlatXmlDataSet.write(fullDataSet, new FileOutputStream("full.xml"));
}
}
```

The problem is that I still get the same error and I don't know why since it should be resolved by setting the qualified table names to true? Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the JDBC driver has a faulty comparison in method: **haveMinimumServerVersion(String ver)** ([link to bug](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CADK3HH%2BuTk4FDhuVxxy_5OJNwcKyR4QaoBZU%2BfJgMnPC%2B364KQ%40mail.gmail.com)). I solved this by using an exclusion in my maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

This solved my problem. I hope it can help somebody else.